# R analysis: how to show the follow-up analysis on a THREE-way interaction?

Tags: javascript, r, lme4, anova

I have used R to run lmer models via the package `lme4`. There are three IVs in my equation: `AverageAoA`, `Imag`, and `PR`. The first two are numeric variables, the last one is categorical.

I am trying to study whether

1. interactions of `AverageAoA*Imag`
2. interactions of `AverageAoA*PR` are significant. Particularly, I would like to see if the two interactions are BOTH SIGNIFICANT when they happen in the same context, thus,
   I tried to run the following part on R:

```
    X0207AverageAoA1.model=lmer(logRT ~ AverageAoA*Imag*PR+ (1|logWordF) + (1|Subject) + (1|Item) + (1|Trialorder) , data=X0207, na.action=na.omit, REML=FALSE)
        
     X0207AverageAoA1.null= lmer(logRT ~ AverageAoA + Imag+ PR + (1|logWordF) + (1|Subject) + (1|Item) + (1|Trialorder) , data=X0207, na.action=na.omit, REML=FALSE)
 
       
     anova(X0207AverageAoA1.null,X0207AverageAoA1.model)
```

However, I only get the output of whether the whole model (X0207AverageAoA1) is significant, as shown in the following:

---

[image: Picture]

---

Is it possible to show whether `AverageAoA*Imag` and `AverageAoA*PR` are significant?